# Unable to install mysql in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-14.04

I am not able to install mysql on ubuntu 14.04, I tried to install various time but not successful. I searched found that complete remove mysql and again reinstall I tried but not able to install. It always give me error unable to set password for root user.

```
Unable to set password for the Mysql "root" user

An error occurred while setting password for the mysql
administrative user.This may have happened because the account already has a password, or because of a communication problem with the Mysql server.
You should check the account's password after the package installation.
Please read the /usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.5/README.Debian file for more information.
```

I search but not successful

Thanks for help